# "Unrecognized type 'employees'. Ignored. C:/....." error when reading input from .xml and writing the output to .xls file + perl

Tags: html, xml, perl

My .xml file has parent element 'employees'. Just I need to extract the contents to '.xls' file. Why am I getting this error:

```
Unrecognized type 'employees'.  Ignored. 
 at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel/FromXML.pm line 325.
```

Any help is appreciated.

My I/p:

```
<employees>
    <employee>
        <name>John Doe</name>
        <age>43</age>
        <sex>M</sex>
        <department>Operations</department>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name>Jane Doe</name>
        <age>31</age>
        <sex>F</sex>
        <department>Accounts</department>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name>Be Goode</name>
        <age>32</age>
        <sex>M</sex>
        <department>Human Resources</department>
    </employee>
</employees>
```

My Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::FromXML;
Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::FromXML->XMLToXLS("emp.xml", "final.xls");
```

O/p:

```
Unrecognized type 'employees'.  Ignored.
 at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel/FromXML.pm line 325.
        Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::FromXML::_processTree(Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::FromXML=HASH(0xea9ad0), ARRAY(0x31da080), "employees", SCALAR(0x31d8de8), SCALAR(0x31d8e00)) called at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel/FromXML.pm line 186
        Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::FromXML::parse(Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::FromXML=HASH(0xea9ad0)) called at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel/FromXML.pm line 79
```

Can any one tell me, why its showing this error? (or) any other method for extracting from .xml to
.xls sheet? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looking at the [source](https://metacpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-FromXML/source/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel/FromXML.pm#L237) it looks like this module only can recognize tags `workbook`, `worksheet`, `row`, `cell`, `format`, `range`, and `margins`. Anything else is considered an error

Comment: Can u (or) anyone suggest me any other module for this extraction?

Comment: Regardless of the module you're going to use, you'll have to specify some rules how your data shall be transformed into tabular form. You could use `XML::XSLT` to produce a structure as required by `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::FromXML`.

Answer (score 2):

Your input data can be transformed into a form accepted by `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::FromXML` using this XSLT template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/employees">
        <workbook>
            <worksheet title="employees">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </worksheet>
        </workbook>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/employees/employee">
        <row>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </row>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/employees/employee/*">
        <cell>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </cell>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

resulting in:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<workbook><worksheet title="employees">
    <row>
        <cell>John Doe</cell>
        <cell>43</cell>
        <cell>M</cell>
        <cell>Operations</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>Jane Doe</cell>
        <cell>31</cell>
        <cell>F</cell>
        <cell>Accounts</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>Be Goode</cell>
        <cell>32</cell>
        <cell>M</cell>
        <cell>Human Resources</cell>
    </row>
</worksheet></workbook>
```

Comment: Is there any other way, without using XSLT?

Comment: TIMTOWTDI. You might convert your xml data to e.g. csv and then convert to xls. You'd need a specification about how to interpret your data in any case - though there might be some "magic" modules that try to guess. I'd expect other solutions to look similar.